# Difference between KDE, MLE and EM for density estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, kernel-smoothing, expectation-maximization, density-estimation

I'm reviewing kernel density estimation (KDE), maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) and expectation maximization (EM) algorithm for density estimation and struggling to differentiate what each algorithm's merits are compared to it's predecessor.

I'm aware that if data has two or more peaks, i.e., it came from two or more unknown distributions, parametric density estimation doesn't work, so we need to go for KDE.

1. But, why do we have to go for MLE when we have KDE to solve for multiple peaks? What does MLE solve that KDE doesn't? I went through this lecture: [Stat Lecture - Washington Univ](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/people/handcock/594/Lectures/lec7.pdf) but couldn't understand the reasoning.

I do understand the framing of MLE for density estimation:
$$
\log[Pr(x_i; \text{dist}, \text{dist params})]
$$

2. Does above formulation still work in cases where data comes from two unknown distributions?
3. If '2' doesn't work, is EM algorithm the solution where there are multiple peaks in data?

   3.b) If EM is solution for data with multiple peaks, then why do we even need MLE for density estimation?
4. What is intuition behind E-Step and using MLE in M-step of EM algorithm?

Any pointers, explanations are high appreciated!

Comment: I think you are confused about a couple of things
1. There is nothing uni-modal about parametric density estimation. For instance, the beta can be bimodal, and you can still fit the parametric beta.
2. You are specifically referring to mixtures models, which are multimodal, but not all multimodal distirbutions are mixture models.
3.  The EM algorithm is just an algorithm for obtaining MLEs that works well with mixture models. However, you could do mixtures without EM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

KDE is a **non-parametric** method: it can be used without specifying any assumptions regarding the density your are trying to estimate. To put it bluntly, if you have a set of $N$ observations $\{x_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq N}$ and absolutely no idea about what their ground-truth distribution $p(x)$ might be, then KDE gives you an estimate $\hat{p}(x)$. The price to pay for this flexibility is a high sensitivity to hyperparameters (i.e. the type of kernel and its bandwidth), since different hyperparameters will lead to greatly different results.

Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE, which I guess is what you are referring to with "Max LLE") refers to a family of methods for performing **parametric** density estimation. Let us assume that you know that your observations $\{x_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq N}$ have been generated from a Gaussian distribution, but that you don't know the parameters $\theta$ (e.g. the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$) of this distribution. MLE gives you an estimate $\hat{\theta}$ of these parameters as the value that maximizes the likelihood of your observations:

$$
\hat{\theta} = \underset{\theta}{\arg\max} \log p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)
$$

i.e.  if you already have assumptions about the shape of the density, but need to infer its exact parameters, then MLE should be used instead of KDE.

EM is a  special way to perform MLE for when your observations were generated from hidden variables, for instance when your model is a Hidden Markov Model or a mixture of distributions.

> I'm aware that if data has two or more peaks, i.e., it came from two
> or more unknown distributions, parametric density estimations doesn't
> work , so we need to go for KDE.

That is not right: the number of modes in the ground-truth distribution has nothing to do with the estimation method to be chosen. If you have no idea (no assumption) about the density you want to estimate, use KDE. If you know the family of the density but want to estimate its parameters (for instance if you know that the density is a mixture of Gaussians but you don't know its weights, means and variances), then use a MLE method such as EM.

[Andrew Ng's lecture notes on EM](https://sgfin.github.io/files/notes/CS229_Lecture_Notes.pdf) should further clarify this.

**ADDENDUM**: the above only focuses on **density estimation** (i.e. fitting a density on observations). If the model includes hidden variables (e.g. is a HMM or a mixture of densities), inferring these hidden variables from observations is a separate problem commonly called **filtering**. [Filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) is a field of research in its own right, and many different methods can be used to infer hidden variables, see for instance [Review 1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022249619301658) or [Review 2](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-30/issue-3/On-Particle-Methods-for-Parameter-Estimation-in-State-Space-Models/10.1214/14-STS511.full). For instance, if the model is a HMM or a mixture of distributions, once the parameters $\theta$ have been estimated (using e.g. the EM algorithm) then the hidden variables can be inferred using the [Viterbi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm).

KDE does not assume any underlying structure for your data, and especially does not assume the presence of hidden variables or of different distributions. However, if KDE yields a multimodal distribution (with several peaks), then it would make sense to assume that data were generated from a mixture of distributions and to use EM (to infer $\theta$) and Viterbi (to infer the hidden variables).

Comment: Thanks much for detailed explanation ! This clarifies a lot of confusions I had. 

Small follow up, when using KDE, if points came from multiple distributions, I'm assuming that it has to do something similar to Max LLE or EM : Probablistically identify which point belongs to which distribution and then identify densities ? 

I guess I just want to know, does KDE separate which points came from which distribution somehow, and then identify their densities separately ?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide more details on filtering.

Comment: Would kernel density be completely non-parametrized? Could one not estimate kernel density via max likelihood, by assuming that the probability distribution is not a simple family but some complex mixture?

Comment: @Cryo I guess by definition, Max LLE is **PARAMETERIZED** , as you'd already make assumptions about what distribution data came from, but just don't know params of it. KDE is by definitions **NON-PARAMETERIZED** , so ya , don't think you need Max LEE to implement KDE, KDE will find out the right distribution and right parameters without explicit assumptions.

Comment: Except the assumptions for the optimizer, and assumptions about the appropriate kernel specification. You don't need ML for KDE, but you are not free from assumptions in either of them. So declaring one parametrized, in bold, and another one non-parametrized is probably a bit of an over-kill.

Comment: BTW lack of explicit assumptions is not a definite benefit. You may want to know exactly what you are assuming